# UriPathExtensionMapping to control response format in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm having a problem getting UriPathExtensionMapping working in ASP.NET WebAPI.  My setup is as follows:

My routes are:

```cs
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Api UriPathExtension",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{extension}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "Api UriPathExtension ID",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}.{extension}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

My Global ASAX file is:

```cs
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

My Controller is:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "Box", "Rectangle" };
}

// GET /api/values/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "Box";
}

// POST /api/values
public void Post(string value)
{
}

// PUT /api/values/5
public void Put(int id, string value)
{
}

// DELETE /api/values/5
public void Delete(int id)
{
}
```

When making requests using curl, JSON is the default response, even when I explicitly request XML I still get JSON:

```
curl http://localhost/eco/api/products/5.xml
```

Returns:

```
"http://www.google.com"
```

Can anyone see the problem with my setup?

The following code maps the extensions in the Global.asax file after the routes have been configured:

```cs
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.
        MediaTypeMappings.Add(
            new UriPathExtensionMapping(
                "json", "application/json"
        )
    );

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.
        MediaTypeMappings.Add(
            new UriPathExtensionMapping(
                "xml", "application/xml"
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you need to register the extension mapping like so:

```cs
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new UriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json"));
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new UriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "application/xml"));
```

Example was found [here](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/issues/150).

**Update**

If you look at the code for [`UriPathExtensionMapping`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Routing/UriPathExtensionMapping.cs) the placeholder for the extension is

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="T:System.Uri"/> path extension key.
/// </summary>
public static readonly string UriPathExtensionKey = "ext";
```

So your routes would need to be changed to ({ext} not {extension}):

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api UriPathExtension",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I already have similar code to set-up the extension mapping (updated the question). I did however change the code to what you suggested, however it still won't work.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to look at the code again - I changed form 'extension' to 'ext' and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to this answer, because I can't comment yet, you should also make sure your web.config contains the line

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

inside the `<system.webServer>` section.

Mine didn't and this example didn't work for me until I added that line.

Comment: Whilst setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` will work it may not be the best option since all static resources will now be processed by all the http modules and have a performance impact. It may be better to leave that off and add a http handler that forces all WebAPI URLs through the pipeline. I added the following to allow my image cache APIs handle requests for *.jpg files 
`<add name="File handler for temp images" path="/api/imagecache/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`

Comment: Yes, I had almost lost hope for this scenario, but your solution survived me again. Thanks